# $ajax don't open the codeinigter controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is the $ajaxCode:

var

```
link="base/try/b";
        alert(link);
            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: "POST",
                data : {"Hello":"hello"}

                success: function(){
                    alert('success');
                  },
                  failure: function(result){
                      console.log("FAILED");
                      console.log(result);
                  }

            });
```

and this is the codeigniter controller:

```
class Try extends CI_controller{
function b(){
echo "HI";
}
}
```

The problem is that the ajas have success and it prints it! but the control doesn't print "HI". Anyone can help me?

Comment: try changing the casing of your class to lowercase "t". Also I'm assuming your not acutally using the word "base" in your link if you are then that is a problem as well. Your link variable should read "/try/b".

Comment: Also you are missing the comma after your data object.

Answer (score 1):

you are posting data to your controller asynchronously. you will never be able to see if the controller echoing `HI`. your ajax has success means that your data successfully submitted to the controller function.
if you want to see that then use `echo json_encode('HI');`